# How can I differentiate regular whitespaces and escaped ones (&#32;) when parsing XML with xml.etree.ElementTree (python)

Tags: python, xml, escaping, html-escape-characters, xml.etree

I'm using `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse an XML file.
How can I force it to either strip text of whitespaces (just regular spaces, not `&#32;`) or leave spaces and ignore escapes (leave them as is)?
Here is my problem:

```
xml_text = """
<root>
    <mytag>
        data_with_space&#32;
    </mytag>
</root>"""
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(xml_text)
mytag = root.find("mytag")
print "original text: ", repr(mytag.text)
print "stripped text: ", repr(mytag.text.strip())
```

It prints:

```
original text:  '\n        data_with_space \n    '
stripped text:  'data_with_space'
```

What I need:

```
'data_with_space '
```

or (which I can escape by other means):

```
'data_with_space&#32;'
```

A solution using `xml.etree.ElementTree` is preferable because I'd have to rewrite a whole lot of code otherwise

Comment: The XML specification treats `&#32;` and the ASCII space character `' '` as identical. You can always replace any character with its `&#...;` equivalent without changing the content of the file as understood by XML tools. You're not going to have any success trying to get an XML library to treat them as different - you need to either change your input XML (by far the best option, if it's actually possible in your situation) or do some ugly and unreliable preprocessing of the string before parsing it as XML.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper sadly, there's nothing I can do about the XML format. It is formed by a different application, and my job is to analyze the data contained within

Comment: I've been there too. Unfortunately, that application is providing data that doesn't maintain the distinction you need to make - an XML parser would be incorrect if it treated `<mytag>foo bar</mytag>` differently than it treated `<mytag>foo&#32;bar</mytag>`. String preprocessing is probably your only option, painful as it is. I hope you can at least narrow down the contexts in which you need to treat the character entity references specially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard XML library treats `&#32;` and `' '` as **equal**. There's no way to avoid the equalization if you directly apply `fromstring(xml_text)`, and therefore it's impossible to differentiate them then. The only way to stop the escaping is to translate it into something else before apply `fromstring()`, and translate it back after then.

---

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

stop_escape   = lambda text: text.replace("&#", "|STOP_ESCAPE|")
resume_escape = lambda text: text.replace("|STOP_ESCAPE|", "&#")

xml_text = """
<root>
    <mytag>
        data_with_space&#32;
    </mytag>
</root>"""
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(stop_escape(xml_text))
mytag_txt = resume_escape(root.find("mytag").text)
print "original text: ", repr(mytag_txt)
print "stripped text: ", repr(mytag_txt.strip())
```

You would get:

```
original text:  '\n        data_with_space&#32;\n    '
stripped text:  'data_with_space&#32;'
```

Comment: Cool. I'm glad to be of help:)